# 3D intersection of a line and a line segment

Tags: geometry

First of all you would be surprise that there's not that much clear solutions for this on stack exchange. I need to know **where**:

- a **line**, defined by a point $P_0$ and a vector $d$
- and a **line segment**, defined by two points $A(a_x, a_y, a_z)$ and $B(b_x, b_y, b_z)$

**intersects** each others.

So far I found [this](https://www.codefull.org/2015/06/intersection-of-a-ray-and-a-line-segment-in-3d/) but it's not even for lines.

Let's agree on $\times$ for cross product and $\cdot$ for the dot one.

Comment: I’m sure this has come up once or twice before on MSE, but you can find solutions and code [here](http://geomalgorithms.com/a05-_intersect-1.html), [here](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/62814.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316490/the-algorithm-to-find-the-point-of-intersection-of-two-3d-line-segment) and many other places.

Comment: Not found with the keywords `line segment intersection`. I found a lot of links online as mentioned in my post. This is used in ray casting as you may know so stack overflow might appreciate a solution in here.

First link: in 2D only.
Third link: two lines segments when I need one line and a line segment.
Don't hesitate to mark as duplicated if you find the answer in here.

Comment: The search function on SE leaves much to be desired, unfortunately. For some reason, you can get better results by looking at the related questions that come up when you enter a question and drilling down into them a bit.

Comment: The linked article is for a line (ray) and a segment. $P_0 = {\rm ray.Origin}$ and $d = \frac{{\rm ray.End - ray.Origin}}{ \| {\rm ray.End - ray.Origin} \|}$

Comment: $ray.End$ looks like the end of the segment line. Plus there's no check for `Vector3.Dot(Vector3.Cross(dc, da), Vector3.Cross(da, db)) / Norm2(Vector3.Cross(da, db));` which is supposed to be between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, let's use
$$\begin{array}{l}
( p_x , p_y , p_z ) = \vec{P}_0 \\
( d_x , d_y , d_z ) = \vec{d} \\
( a_x , a_y , a_z ) = \vec{a} \\
( b_x , b_y , b_z ) = \vec{b}
\end{array}$$

Let's parametrise the line using $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and the line segment using $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $0 \le t \le 1$:
$$\vec{P}_0 + s \vec{d} = (1 - t) \vec{a} + t \vec{b} = \vec{a} + t \left ( \vec{b} - \vec{a} \right)$$
i.e.
$$\begin{cases}
p_x + s d_x = (1 - t) a_x + t b_x \\
p_y + s d_y = (1 - t) a_y + t b_y \\
p_z + s d_z = (1 - t) a_z + t b_z \end{cases}$$
You have three equations, but only two unknowns. Furthermore, because all real $s$ are acceptable, you only need to solve for $t$, and verify it $0 \le t \le 1$. There are three solutions, subscripted by which coordinate pair is used in the solution:
$$t_{xy} = \frac{ d_y ( a_x - p_x ) - d_x ( a_y - p_y ) }{ d_y ( a_x - b_x ) - d_x ( a_y - b_y ) } \tag{1}\label{1}$$
$$t_{xz} = \frac{ d_z ( a_x - p_x ) - d_x ( a_z - p_z ) }{ d_z ( a_x - b_x ) - d_x ( a_z - b_z ) } \tag{2}\label{2}$$
$$t_{yz} = \frac{ d_z ( a_y - p_y ) - d_y ( a_z - p_z ) }{ d_z ( a_y - b_y ) - d_y ( a_z - b_z ) } \tag{3}\label{3}$$
For numerical accuracy, I suggest you calculate all three denominators first, and calculate $t$ using the formula corresponding to the largest denominator in magnitude (absolute value).

If all three denominators are zero, the line and the line segment do not intersect. (This can also occur if $\vec{P}_0 = \vec{d}$ or $\vec{a} = \vec{b}$ or both.)

In case you wish to check for the intersection between two line segments, here are the corresponding formulae for $s$:
$$s_{xy} = \frac{ a_x ( b_y - p_y ) - b_x ( a_y - p_y ) + p_x ( a_y - b_y ) }{ d_y ( a_x - b_x ) - d_x ( a_y - b_y ) } \tag{4}\label{4}$$
$$s_{xz} = \frac{ a_x ( b_z - p_z ) - b_x ( a_z - p_z ) + p_x ( a_z - b_z ) }{ d_z ( a_x - b_x ) - d_x ( a_z - b_z ) } \tag{5}\label{5}$$
$$s_{yz} = \frac{ a_y ( b_z - p_z ) - b_y ( a_z - p_z ) + p_y ( a_z - b_z ) }{ d_z ( a_y - b_y ) - d_y ( a_z - b_z ) } \tag{6}\label{6}$$

Note that the corresponding formulae for $s$ have the same denominators; that is, $\eqref{1}$ and $\eqref{4}$ have the same denominators, $\eqref{2}$ and $\eqref{5}$ have the same denominators, and $\eqref{3}$ and $\eqref{6}$ have the same denominators. (This means that if a solution for $t$ exists, a solution exists for $s$ also. In OP's case $s$ does not matter, because it is the parameter for an infinite line, and any real $s$ is acceptable.)

If you find $t$, and $0 \le t \le 1$, the line and the line segment intersect at $\vec{v}$,
$$\vec{v} = (1-t) \vec{a} + t \vec{b}$$
i.e.
$$\begin{cases}
v_x = (1-t) a_x + t b_x \\
v_y = (1-t) a_y + t b_y \\
v_z = (1-t) a_z + t b_z \end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer, unfortunately I need to know where the intersection is and not if there's one.

Comment: @Deewy: I thought it was obvious: If there is a $t$, $0 \le t \le 1$, then the line segment intersects the line at $(1-t)\vec{a} + t \vec{b}$, because $t$ parametrizes the line segment. I added the explicit intersection point $\vec{v}$ to the answer.

Comment: It was obvious you are right. Thanks a lot for all the effort you put in here.

Comment: when I try to see if the intersection of the line segment delimited by $A=(-1,0,0)$ and $B=(1,0,0)$ with the line starting at $P_0=(0,-2,0)$ in direction of $v=(0,1,0)$. I find no intersection when $(0,0,0)$ should be the one. Maybe you forgot to mention that $t$ has to be in absolute value in the final equation ?

Comment: @Deewy: No, the formulas match. Substituting to (1) you should get $$t_{xy} = \frac{ 1 \left( (-1) - (0) \right) - 0 \left( (0) - (-2) \right) }{ 1 \left( (-1) - (1) \right) - 0 \left( (0) - (0) \right) } = \frac{ -1 }{-2} = \frac{1}{2}$$which means the intersection is midway between $A$ and $B$, as it should be.

Comment: You're right, as always sorry for my inattentions mistakes.

Comment: @Deewy: No worries; I make mistakes too, and it's good to keep a sharp eye and ask if something does not seem to match.

Answer (score 2):

The line is given by $\{ td+P_0\mid t\in\mathbb R\}$ and the segment by $\{ (1-s)A+sB\mid s\in[0,1]\}$. You need a point in both sets. The easiest way to go about this is to extend the segement into a line by letting $s\in\mathbb R$ instead of just $[0,1]$ and solve linear system $$td+P_0 = (1-s)A + sB$$ for $t$ and $s$. After that, you need to check if $s$ is in $[0,1]$ or not. Also, note that the linear system in 3D is overdetermined, so there might be no solutions at all.

Comment: you should treat the case where the segment is included in the line to avoid the case where you have infinite solutions

Comment: @stity, I don't see why this should be treated separately, whatever the case you have will become apparent from the system and augmented system matrix. But if OP wishes, I can write down detailed analysis.